# Is $f(x,y)=\sqrt{|xy|}$ differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I know that $f(x,y)=\sqrt{|xy|}$ when $(x,y)\neq{(0,0)}$ is differentiable since partial derivatives exist and they're continous.
When I do by definition $f_x (0,0)$ and $f_y (0,0)$, both are equal to $0$.
Due to "Sufficient Condition for the Differentiability of Functions", can I conclude that it is differentiable? 
My problem is that I think it isn't diff. because of an analogy to single-variable $f(x)=|x|$, but not sure.
Thanks.

Comment: You may want to second-guess existence of partial derivatives for $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$.

Comment: I thought about using other directions. However the theorem says that partial derivatives are needed, or maybe i'm confusing myself.

Comment: Nevermind! I was misreading your post, thank you very much!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477913/fx-y-sqrtxy?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is *not* differentiable (since, for instance, its restriction to $\{(x,x)\mid x\in\mathbb R\}$ is not differentiable). Note that, if $x,y>0$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=\frac12\sqrt{\frac yx}$. And we *don't* have $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac12\sqrt{\frac yx}=0=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)$. So, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is *not* continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Nice way to prove it! Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but if the partial derivative isn't continuous at a point, it doesn't mean that the function is not differentiable, does it?

Comment: No. That's why my first sentence contains a proof that $f$ is not differentiable. The rest of my answer shows that you were wrong when you stated that the partial derivatives are continuous.

Comment: Oh sorry! I can see it now, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $f(x,x)=|x|.$ Is that the way a differentiable function behaves?

Comment: Yes! I was exactly thinking about that